# Apache CXFRS and CAMEL configuration

Tags: cxfrs

i want to consume the REST result by hitting a REST web Service available at `http://someotherhost` site. i have written a proxy client for it

I want to hit the above REST service using apache CXFRS client and the write the result to a file. for which i am doing the following,could any one review the below and comment the things i have done wrong .

a) My camel context configuration with apache cxf is as below

```
    <jaxrs:client address="http://someotherhost/test/" id="cityServiceClient" username="test"         
            password="pwd" 
            serviceClass="com.santosh.proxy.service.city.CityService">
            <jaxrs:features>
                    <ref bean="loggingFeature" />
            </jaxrs:features>
    </jaxrs:client>  

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
            <package>com.santosh.routes</package>
            <routeBuilder ref="cityserviceroutebuilder" />
    </camelContext>
```

b) MY Proxy service Interface

```
    @Path(value="/getCities") 
    public interface CityService   { 

       @POST 
       @Produces(value="text/xml") 
       public String getCities(@QueryParam("countrycode") String countryCode); 
    }
```

c)  Call to service

```
   CityService cityService = (CityService) context.getBean("cityServiceClient"); 
   cityService.getCities("ae");
```

d) Camel Routes

```
  public class CityRoutes extends RouteBuilder { 

    public void configure() throws Exception { 

   //ROUTES 
    from("cxfbean:cityServiceClient") 
      .to("file://data/xmls/cities?fileName=test.xml"); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution, basically my camel-context configuration was not up to that mark,

The below configuration solved my problem.

```
    <! -- 4 THE ACTUAL SERVER WHICH WILL GET HIT -->
    <jaxrs:server id="restService" depends-on="camelContext" 
            address="http://REALSERVER.COM/REST/" createdFromAPI="true" 
            staticSubresourceResolution="true">
            <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
                    <ref bean="servicecity" />
            </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    </jaxrs:server>

    <bean name="servicecity" id="servicecity" class="com.santosh.CityServiceImpl" />


    <! -- 3  YOUR PROXY CLIENT -->
    <cxf:rsClient id="rsClient" address="http://REALSERVER.COM/REST/"  
                              serviceClass="com.santosh.CityServiceImpl" 
                      username="santosh" password="pwd" />

    <! -- 1 JAXRS PROXY CLIENT  -->  
    <jaxrs:client id="cityServiceClient" address="http://localhost:8123/REST/"
            serviceClass="com.santosh.CityService" username="santosh" password="pwd">
    </jaxrs:client>

   <! -- 2  YOUR LOCAL SERVER THAT YOU NEED TO HIT, YOUR LOCAL SERVER -->
    <cxf:rsServer id="rsServer" address="http://localhost:8123/REST/" serviceClass="com.santosh.CityServiceImpl" />
```

THE STEPS ARE

1)  create  JAXRS PROXY CLIENT and get it in your have code 
       CityService cityService = (CityService) context.getBean("cityServiceClient"); 
       cityService.getCities("INDIA");

2) the above code will call the SERVER (LOCAL)

3)  the above step  will call  YOUR PROXY CLIENT

4) the PROXY CLIENT will call the ACTUAL REAL SERVER